# WinForm application crashes after publishing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, publish

I have a Winform application that I publish to use on other computers.
After a while, I get an error and the app crash, this is the log I'm getting:

```
  Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: AppName.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 5cb4e429
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.7.2650.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5ab1c3d4
  Problem Signature 07: 4d6
  Problem Signature 08: 4f
  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentOutOfRange
  OS Version:   6.3.9600.2.0.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 829c
  Additional Information 2: 829cca39ba8c9b3fc87bc891d75921bb
  Additional Information 3: 0531
  Additional Information 4: 0531a8d7f80ac7c1c84bcb79166ded7e

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=280262

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

There is any way to get the Class+method that crash the application?
Thanks!

Comment: It seems like the method call receives invalid arguments, but i am not sure.

Comment: `Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentOutOfRange` add proper exception handling and logging.